# Does NetBeans 7.0 has built in support for spring 3.0?

Tags: java, spring, netbeans, jakarta-ee

I want to use spring 3.0.5 in NetBeans 7.0 IDE.. I have done following steps

1. Created a new Web Application project
2. downloaded the jars of spring framework
3. Added the jar folder to project library

but still it is not working... the default domain object "command" is not accessible inside my htm / jsp pages.

can anyone help me on this ?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can tell for sure is that spring framework 3.0.2 is available. When I create a new web application, I can select the framework.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans 7.0 has support for Spring 3.0, Hibernate, JSF, etc

For Complete instructions & tutorial for NetBeans+Spring go to : http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html